# Get all rows from two tables with SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have two tables in a SQLite database, I'll call them `tableA` and `tableB`. How can I construct a query to return all rows from `tableA` and `tableB` (each row on one line)? I was trying something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM tableA AS A LEFT JOIN tableB AS B;
```

When I run the query above, my results are not quite what I'm looking for; I get a row from `tableA` and a row from `tableB` on the same line. I simply want to return all the rows, each on a unique line from both of these two tables. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [UNION](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_unions_clause.htm) statement:

```
SELECT * FROM tableA
UNION
SELECT * FROM tableB
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks. I didn't know there was a UNION in SQL.